# Grouping and filtering a sequence in F#

Tags: f#

I have some data from a SQL dB that looks similar to

```
recordID value date    
A        4     11/20/14
A        1     11/25/14
B        5     01/10/15
B        2     01/20/15
C        10    11/20/14
C        3     11/25/14
C        5     11/30/14
```

but with tens of thousands of rows.

My goal is, for each `recordID`, to keep the row that corresponds to the latest date after applying a date filter.

I can easily filter the data with

```ml
let filteredData = table 
                |> Seq.filter (fun x -> System.DateTime.Compare(x.Date.Value, convertStringToDate "1/15/15")) <= 0)
```

(The function `convertStringToDate` is a wrapper for `System.DateTime.Parse`.)

The `let` statement above returns a sequence of rows that includes only the rows that are equal to or before `"1/15/15"` but what I eventually need is a sequence of dB rows for which each `recordID` is represented once by it's maximum, *filtered* date.

I suspect that I'll be using `Seq.groupBy` in some way but as a relatively new user of `F#`, I'm missing how I can use it here.  [I did not find the `Seq.groupBy` example on the MSDN page very helpful.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370445.aspx)

Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you `groupBy` your records by `recordID`, which gives you a sequence of sequences of each `recordId`. Then of each latter sequence you drop the group key and filter out all, but the record instance with latest `date`:

```
type Row = {recordID: string; value: int; date: DateTime}

let s = seq {
            yield {recordID = "A"; value = 4; date = DateTime.Parse "11/20/2014"}
            yield {recordID = "A"; value = 1; date = DateTime.Parse "11/25/2014"}
            yield {recordID = "B"; value = 5; date = DateTime.Parse "1/10/2015"}
            yield {recordID = "B"; value = 2; date = DateTime.Parse "1/20/2015"}
        }

let filterLatest ss =
    ss
    |> Seq.groupBy (fun x -> x.recordID)
    |> Seq.map (snd >> Seq.maxBy (fun x -> x.date))
```

In FSI:

```
s |> filterLatest
```

produces the expected

```
seq [{recordID = "A"; value = 1; date = "11/25/2014 12:00:00 AM"};
     {recordID = "B"; value = 2; date = "1/20/2015 12:00:00 AM"}]
```

Comment: Perfect.  Worked great!